# Count(*) doesn't give "1" back, although my &inputs is correct?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables in my database

```
SQL> desc finance_orders;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 ORDER_NUM                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 CLIENT_ID                                          NUMBER(8)
 FINANCE_NAME                                       VARCHAR2(32)
 FINANCE_AMMOUNT                                    NUMBER(10)
 IN_HMY                                             NUMBER(3)
 ORDER_DATE                                         DATE
 ORDER_STATUS                                       VARCHAR2(32)

SQL> desc finance_types;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 FIN_NAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 FIN_MIN                                            NUMBER(10)
 FIN_MAX                                            NUMBER(10)
 FIN_APR                                            NUMBER(5,2)
 MGMT_COST                                          NUMBER(10)
 DOUBLE_SAL                                         NUMBER(5)

SQL> desc client_accounts;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 CLIENT_ID                                          NUMBER(8)
 CARD_NUM                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(13)
 CVC                                                NUMBER(3)
 ISS_DATE                                           DATE
 EXP_DATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(10)
 BALANCE                                            NUMBER(10)
```

Two tables are already filled, the third is empty.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNTS;

 CLIENT_ID   CARD_NUM        CVC ISS_DATE  EXP_DATE         SAL    BALANCE
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------- ----------
  10000000 6.6028E+12        113 12-DEC-18 11-DEC-21      15000
  10001500 6.4924E+12        461 12-DEC-18 11-DEC-21      15000

SQL> SELECT * FROM FINANCE_TYPES;

FIN_NAME                            FIN_MIN    FIN_MAX    FIN_APR  MGMT_COST DOUBLE_SAL
-------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
CAR                                   45000     500000       4.85       2500         25
HOME                                 120000  250000000       12.7       8500         60
PERSONAL                               2000     180000       3.58        500         15
```

So, I went to make a query using `count(*)` to check before I primary insert any value into the `finance_orders` table. Just check, not add.

This is the code:

```
  1 SELECT Count(*)
  2 FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNTS CA , FINANCE_TYPES FT ,FINANCE_ORDERS FO
  3 WHERE
  4 FO.CLIENT_ID= &CLIENT_ID --here i use this to check
  5 AND
  6 FO.FINANCE_NAME = '&FIN_NAME' --here i use this to check
  7 AND
  8 FO.CLIENT_ID = CA.CLIENT_ID
  9 AND
 10 FO.FINANCE_NAME = FT.FIN_NAME
 11 AND
 12 ((((CA.SAL)*(FT.DOUBLE_SAL)) BETWEEN FT.FIN_MIN AND FT.FIN_MAX) OR (((CA.SAL)*(FT.DOUBLE_SAL)) > FT.FIN_MAX) )

SQL> /
Enter value for client_id: 10000000
old   4:                  FO.CLIENT_ID= &CLIENT_ID
new   4:                  FO.CLIENT_ID= 10000000
Enter value for fin_name: PERSONAL
old   6:                                          FO.FINANCE_NAME = '&FIN_NAME'
new   6:                                          FO.FINANCE_NAME = 'PERSONAL'

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

I use "&input" as a way to check, for sorry, the `count(*)` won't be able to give "1" back.

You could see that the client "10000000" his salary "15000$" and his finance type minimum and maximum and double_sal are all met and true, so `count(*)` must be 1.

The table is empty. If `count(*)` doesn't work with empty tables, then what would do it? triggers?

Comment: You have WHERE FO.CLIENT_ID= &CLIENT_ID, but have nothing in your FO table so how do you expect that to return 1 instead of 0? This query is working properly.

Comment: @JayMason ops, but, I thought count(*) is built to check as the if statement, &client_id as a Temporary variable, so I guess there's no need to insert anything into the table, so I'm wondering why count(*) won't except it as like it exists?

Comment: That makes no sense Abe... If you have no records in your database and you are telling your query that you want to join these tables where your client ID matches, You are telling it "hey find me records that connect these 3 tables, with these values"...

Comment: So what that really means is for every 3 rows that match up (one for each table) your count will increase by 1. Your count is 0 because you have no records in that database

Comment: when in doubt fist to go is WHERE clause then JOIN gets changed to LEFT (possible with driver table i.e. main table) leading the way. In your case the table that has values. if you get what you expect then start adding WHERE clause back 1 at a time to get back to where you are. In process see why result-sets are changing.

Comment: If you're trying to find out if you need to insert a row or not, this does not sound like the best way of doing it. Perhaps doing the insert as a merge statement (meaning that you only insert the row if it doesn't already exist in the target table) would help you achieve your aim in a more performant way.

Answer (score 0):

One of your table is empty but you are joining your tables with inner join. Since finance_orders table is empty you are joining your records with null thus the query returns 0 records.

Comment: so, if count(*) won't work, would "trigger" done this better?